# Is it possible to rewind a PDO result?

Tags: php, iterator, pdo

I'm trying to write an iterator for results from a PDO statement but I can't find any way of rewinding to the first row. I would like to avoid the overhead of calling fetchAll and storing all the result data.

```
// first loop works fine
foreach($statement as $result) {
    // do something with result
}

// but subsequent loops don't
foreach($statement as $result) {
    // never called 
}
```

Is there some way of reseting the statement or seeking the first row?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is database dependent. Because of that, it is something you should try to avoid. However, I think you can achieve what you want by enabling [buffered queries](http://www.php.net/pdo-mysql#pdo-mysql.constants). If that doesn't work, you can always pull the result into an array with [`fetchAll`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php). Both solutions have implications for your applications performance, so think twice about it, if the resultsets are large.

Answer (score 11):

This little class I wrote wraps a PDOStatement. It only stores the data that is fetched. If this doesn't work, you could move the cache to read and write to a file.

```
// Wrap a PDOStatement to iterate through all result rows. Uses a 
// local cache to allow rewinding.
class PDOStatementIterator implements Iterator
{
    public
        $stmt,
        $cache,
        $next;

    public function __construct($stmt)
    {
        $this->cache = array();
        $this->stmt = $stmt;
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        reset($this->cache);
        $this->next();
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return (FALSE !== $this->next);
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return $this->next[1];
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return $this->next[0];
    }

    public function next()
    {
        // Try to get the next element in our data cache.
        $this->next = each($this->cache);

        // Past the end of the data cache
        if (FALSE === $this->next)
        {
            // Fetch the next row of data
            $row = $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // Fetch successful
            if ($row)
            {
                // Add row to data cache
                $this->cache[] = $row;
            }

            $this->next = each($this->cache);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

see [slide 31 from this presentation](http://somabo.de/talks/200311_apachecon_php5_and_databases.pdf), you can do a `$statement->rewind()` if it applies to a buffered query. If you use mysql, you can emulate buffered queries by using `PDO_MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY`:

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, 1);
```

@NoahGoodrich pointed you to spl. Here is an example that always works:

```
$it = new ArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll());
```

Answer (score 3):

Asked a long time ago but currently there's another solution.

The method `PDOStatement::fetch()` may receives a second parameter, the cursor orientation, with one of `PDO::FETCH_ORI_*` constants. These parameter are only valid if the `PDOStatement` are created with the atribute `PDO::ATTR_CURSOR` as `PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL`.

This way you can navigate as follows.

```
$sql = "Select * From Tabela";
$statement = $db->prepare($sql, array(
    PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL,
));
$statement->execute();
$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH, PDO::FETCH_ORI_NEXT);  // return next
$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH, PDO::FETCH_ORI_PRIOR); // return previous
$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH, PDO::FETCH_ORI_FIRST); // return first
$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH, PDO::FETCH_ORI_LAST);  // return last
$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH, PDO::FETCH_ORI_ABS, $n); // return to $n position
$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH, PDO::FETCH_ORI_REL, $n); // return to $n position relative to current
```

More info in [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php#refsect1-pdostatement.fetch-parameters) and [PDO predefined constants](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php).

Note: used `PDO::FETCH_BOTH` because is the default, just customize it for your project.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to take a look at some of the PHP SPL classes that can be extended to provide array-like access to objects.

- [Standard PHP Library (SPL)](http://us.php.net/spl) I would specifically
  recommend that you look at the
  ArrayIterator, ArrayObject, and
  perhaps the Iterator interface.
- [Simple
  Tutorial](http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php)
- [Another
  Quick Tutorial](http://ramikayyali.com/archives/2005/02/25/iterators)