# How can I rewind a pdo result?

Tags: php, pdo

I know this question has been asked before, but I tried eveything and can't find how it works. 
I have a prepared query, and I need to use it twice with two while() loops like this:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT ...');
$query->execute();
while( $results = $query->fetch() ){
 // instructions
}

// rewind
while( $results = $query->fetch() ){
 // instructions
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278259/is-it-possible-to-rewind-a-pdo-result

Comment: I know, I've seen this post but I didn't understand how to make it work.

Comment: If you ask the same question you risk getting the same answer.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario but the OP ddnt.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could be as simple as getting all the results on the 1st iteration and loop on the 2nd:

```
$res = array();
while( $results = $query->fetch() ){
   $res[] = $results;
   // instructions
}

foreach($res as $results){
   // instructions
}
```

Comment: Actually, you'd just have to use `fetchAll` and get rid of the first loop.

Comment: Way easier than everything I've seen, and it works. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

To expand on above answer, you could use:

```
$results = $query->fetchAll();
```

$results now being an array containing the result set, so:

```
foreach ($results as $row) ...
```

Alternatively with MySQL, you can use buffered queries:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT ...', array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true));
```

The fetchAll() method will be database vendor independent, but will have higher memory requirements.

Comment: Yes, but with fetchAll() you have to use the number of the row like this: $result[0], then $result[1]... but I need to use some code in the second loop for the result that has the same number in the first, but not for all the result. So I don't know the number. (I don't know if I'm clear...)