# PHP Execute array multple times on the one page

Tags: php, arrays

I want to run two seperate foreach loops on the one page, but only write my SQL once.  For example see the below code, only the ul with the id of first runs, the second ul is empty.

```
    <?php
        $mylist = 'SELECT * FROM myTable';
        $showlist = $pdo->prepare($mylist);
        $showlist->execute();
    ?>  
    <ul id="first">
        <?php foreach ($showlist as $rowid):;?>
            <li><?php echo $rowid['id'] ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>  
    </ul>
    <ul id="second">
        <?php foreach ($showlist as $rowname):;?>
            <li><?php echo $rowname['name'] ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>  
    </ul>
```

I thought renaming the as would allow me to use it again but this doesn't seem to be the case?  What is the best approach here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278259/is-it-possible-to-rewind-a-pdo-result

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo fair call re being a duplicate.  I think the two answers here are better than the other site though in terms of giving an example of how to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
<?php
$mylist = 'SELECT * FROM myTable';
$showlist = $pdo->prepare($mylist);
$showlist->execute();
$result = $showlist->fetchAll();

foreach ($result as $rowid) {
    // do stuff
}

foreach ($result as $rowname) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to stack your elements in an extra array first:

```
$mylist = 'SELECT * FROM myTable';
$showlist = $pdo->prepare($mylist);
$showlist->execute();

$rows = array();

foreach($showlist as $row) {
    array_push($rows, $row);
}

echo "<ul>";
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo "<li>".$row['id']."</li>";
}
echo "</ul><ul>";
foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo "<li>".$row['name']."</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```