# PDO class - fetching results after initial fetch

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this is my PDO class

```
<?php
class Database
{
    protected $dbh;
    protected $query;
    public $rows;

    public function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$dbname)
    {
        // Set DSN
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $dbname;

        // Set options
        $options = array(   PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT=> true,
                            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=> PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        // Create a new PDO instanace
        try
        {
            $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
        }
        catch(PDOException $e)
        {
            echo $this->error = $e->getMessage();
            die();
        }
    }

    public function query($query)
    {
        $this->query = $this->dbh->query($query);
    }

    public function execute($array=null)
    {
        $this->stmt->execute($array);
    }

    public function fetchAllQuery()//--------------------(1)
    {
        $resultQuery = $this->query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $this->rows = count($resultQuery);
        return $resultQuery;
    }

    public function fetchQuery()//------------(2)
    {
        return $this->query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }

    public function rowCountQuery()///////////////
    {
       return $this->rows;
    }
```

}

```
$database = new Database('localhost','root','','speed');

$query  = $database->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_deliverygrid"); 
$result = $database->fetchAllQuery();//--------------calling method (1)
echo '<pre>',print_r($result),'</pre><br>';


while($result2 = $database->fetchQuery())//----------calling method (2)
{
    echo $result2['area'];
    echo '<br>';
}
```

- after calling (1) method i'm not able to get results calling (2) method
- and also after calling (2) method i'm not able to get results calling (1) method

how to use both (1) and (2) methods simultaneously for getting results ?

Comment: That is expected behavior. The first time, you call `fetchAll()` so there are no remaining rows to fetch the second time. If you execute a new query, you will be able to fetch again incrementally.

Comment: See [is it possible to rewind a PDO result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278259/is-it-possible-to-rewind-a-pdo-result) -- it looks like you are just testing functionality of your class. In practice, it would be very unusual to fetch all rows, then immediately try to fetch them again (since you already have them in the variable `$result`) but for what you're doing here, it is working as it should.